# Separation from family of closed and connected subsets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $X $ be a compact $T_0$ topological space and let $\{ A_i \}_{ i \in I }$ be a family of closed and connected subsets of $X $ and $  x\in X$ such that for each $i\in I $ there exists a closed and open (clopen) subset $ T $ of $ X $  such that $x\in T  $ and $A_i\subseteq X\setminus T $. How can we find a closed and open (clopen) subset $ U $ of $ X $  such that $x\in U  $ and $\cup_{ i \in I } A_i\subseteq X\setminus U $?

If it is not true , under what conditions it may be true?
Note: Actually  $A_i's$ are contained in different connected components.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where it is not possible to find such a subset $U$. Let $X = \{0\} \cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}  }[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1 + n}{n^2}] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

This is Hausdorff hence $ T_{0}$ and compact since it is closed and bounded. Let $x =0$ and $A_{i} = [\frac{1}{i},\frac{1+i}{i^2}]$ for $i \geq 2$.